# How to create multi bit rate dash content using ffmpeg dash muxer

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-dash

`ffmpeg` [documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#dash-2) says that we can use dash muxer to create dash segments and manifest file with just a single command, like:

```
ffmpeg -re -i <input> -map 0 -map 0 -c:a libfdk_aac -c:v libx264
-b:v:0 800k -b:v:1 300k -s:v:1 320x170 -profile:v:1 baseline
-profile:v:0 main -bf 1 -keyint_min 120 -g 120 -sc_threshold 0
-b_strategy 0 -ar:a:1 22050 -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1
-window_size 5 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a"
-f dash /path/to/out.mpd
```

Saying I have some HD video file and I want this video to be available through DASH in different bit rates, so that clients can automatically select from the alternatives based on current network conditions. Can all these be done with a single `ffmpeg` command, like given above?

I know there is a solution with using ffmpeg + mp4box, but i'm interested if it could be done with `ffmpeg` only.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so this is how I resolved my problem. Following commands are useful for implementing pseudo-live dash content (it's when you want to stream existing video file as if it were a live video) but also the same approach could be used for on-demand video. First, we transform an input video file (sample.divx) into another, well prepared for dash streaming video file - sample_dash.mp4:

```
ffmpeg -y -i sample.divx ^
  -c:v libx264 -x264opts "keyint=24:min-keyint=24:no-scenecut" -r 24 ^
  -c:a aac -b:a 128k ^
  -bf 1 -b_strategy 0 -sc_threshold 0 -pix_fmt yuv420p ^
  -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0 ^
  -b:v:0 250k  -filter:v:0 "scale=-2:240" -profile:v:0 baseline ^
  -b:v:1 750k  -filter:v:1 "scale=-2:480" -profile:v:1 main ^
  -b:v:2 1500k -filter:v:2 "scale=-2:720" -profile:v:2 high ^
  sample_dash.mp4
```

I'm saying sample_dash.mp4 is well prepared because it's encoded in a good for dash format - H264/ACC and it's containing multiple (3) video streams with different qualities (baseline, main, high). ffmpeg dash muxer will translate these 3 video streams into relevant alternative video quality deash segment files. Here is how:

```
ffmpeg -y -re -i sample_dash.mp4 ^
  -map 0 ^
  -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1 -window_size 5 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v id=1,streams=a" ^
  -f dash sample.mpd
```

`-re` flags tells ffmpeg to process the input video in a realtime manner, which is useful for pseudo-live streaming.

Comment: Like You have originally asked is it possible to do all this in single command?

Comment: it can be treated as one command only. If you are using java, rest can be supplied as arguments to command

Comment: It seems that separating the commands causes ffmpeg to recode on the second one, is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: @Ell probably not, to avoid that just add `-c copy`

Answer (score 10):

With the help of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50310145/1610034) and [documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#dash-2), Following is the way to do this in single command:

```
ffmpeg -i $inputFile \
  -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a\?:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a\?:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a\?:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a\?:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a\?:0 -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a\?:0  \
  -b:v:0 350k  -c:v:0 libx264 -filter:v:0 "scale=320:-1"  \
  -b:v:1 1000k -c:v:1 libx264 -filter:v:1 "scale=640:-1"  \
  -b:v:2 3000k -c:v:2 libx264 -filter:v:2 "scale=1280:-1" \
  -b:v:3 245k  -c:v:3 libvpx-vp9 -filter:v:3 "scale=320:-1"  \
  -b:v:4 700k  -c:v:4 libvpx-vp9 -filter:v:4 "scale=640:-1"  \
  -b:v:5 2100k -c:v:5 libvpx-vp9 -filter:v:5 "scale=1280:-1"  \
  -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1 -window_size 6 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v  id=1,streams=a" \
  -hls_playlist true -f dash output/output.mpd
```

Comment: If you're getting the error `Only '-vf scale=320:-1' read, ignoring remaining -vf options: Use ',' to separate filters`, this is actually not impacting the filters.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is where you think the filter is applied.
In the ffmpeg logic video filters are applied "after" the stream are decoded and "before" they are encoded (no matter where you put them in the command line)

By consequence that they cannot be used in the way you are using them.

Probably the best way in your case is using a filter complex that immediately after its decoded, first split the video in 4 different intermediate videos, then apply a different scaling to each of them, then take their output and encode them.

something like this (i'm reducind to two different variants for shortness, i'm sure you can readapt for 6):

```
ffmpeg -i $inputFile -filter_complex "[0]split=6[mid0][mid1];[mid0]scale=320:-1[out0];[mid1]scale=640:-1[out1]" -map [out0] -map 0:a -map [out1] -map 0:a -c:a aac -c:v:0 libx264 -c:v:1 libvpx-vp9 -use_timeline 1 -use_template 1 -window_size 6 -adaptation_sets "id=0,streams=v  id=1,streams=a" -hls_playlist true -f dash output/output.mpd
```

It's just an example, hope it will bring you to the right track :)